# Parsing JSONData in ngForm

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I want to iterate the below JSON **JsonRawData** object in AngularJs2. For this I am using the below code :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of userData;">
                <tr *ngFor="let subitem of item.JsonRawData;" >
```

But it throw me the exception 
i.e. **Error**:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '
>   [{"USER_ID":null,"firstName":"......":null}]' of type 'string'. NgFor
>   only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

**My JSON from Web API:**

```
[
  {
    "USER_ID": "a8717928-2e87-4627-b3c3-2e2549f0dc48",
    "**JsonRawData**": " [{\"USER_ID\":null,\"firstName\":\"sumit\",\"lastName\":\"joshi\",\"landline\":\"01127850127\",\"phone\":null,\"gender\":\"Married\",\"maritalstatus\":\"D\",\"gotra\":\"Kaushik\",\"dob\":{\"date\":{\"year\":\"2017\",\"month\":\"12\",\"day\":\"24\"},\"jsdate\":\"\",\"formatted\":\"\",\"epoc\":\"\"},\"birthplace\":\"Delhi\",\"time\":{\"hh\":\"12\",\"min\":\"1\",\"sec\":\"49\"},\"password\":\"12234\",\"confirmPassword\":\"\",\"height\":\"5.7\",\"weight\":\"84\",\"incomerange\":\"10000-20000\",\"smokestatus\":\"Yes\",\"dietstatus\":\"Veg\",\"workstatus\":\"job\",\"drinkstatus\":\"No\",\"religion\":\"Hindu\",\"mothertounge\":\"Hindi\",\"rashi\":\"5\",\"education\":\"MBA\",\"profession\":\"Job\",\"address\":\"Roihini\",\"country\":\"india\",\"city\":\"delhi\",\"place\":\"delhi\",\"zip\":\"110089\",\"about\":\"about me\",\"mySubCaste\":\"joshi\",\"recaptcha\":\"\",\"email\":\"a11rtg52@a.com\",\"nativeplace\":null,\"mobile\":\"9650899699\",\"JsonRawData\":null}]",
    "USER_PEROFILE_ID": 1
  },
  {
    "USER_ID": "c007dfca-f478-4794-b190-97fb1d5667c3",
    "JsonRawData": "[{\"USER_ID\":null,\"firstName\":\"sumit\",\"lastName\":\"joshi\",\"landline\":\"01127850127\",\"phone\":null,\"gender\":\"Married\",\"maritalstatus\":\"D\",\"gotra\":\"Kaushik\",\"dob\":{\"date\":{\"year\":\"2017\",\"month\":\"12\",\"day\":\"24\"},\"jsdate\":\"\",\"formatted\":\"\",\"epoc\":\"\"},\"birthplace\":\"Delhi\",\"time\":{\"hh\":\"12\",\"min\":\"1\",\"sec\":\"49\"},\"password\":\"12234\",\"confirmPassword\":\"\",\"height\":\"5.7\",\"weight\":\"84\",\"incomerange\":\"10000-20000\",\"smokestatus\":\"Yes\",\"dietstatus\":\"Veg\",\"workstatus\":\"job\",\"drinkstatus\":\"No\",\"religion\":\"Hindu\",\"mothertounge\":\"Hindi\",\"rashi\":\"5\",\"education\":\"MBA\",\"profession\":\"Job\",\"address\":\"Roihini\",\"country\":\"india\",\"city\":\"delhi\",\"place\":\"delhi\",\"zip\":\"110089\",\"about\":\"about me\",\"mySubCaste\":\"joshi\",\"recaptcha\":\"\",\"email\":\"a1138412@a.com\",\"nativeplace\":null,\"mobile\":\"9650899699\",\"JsonRawData\":null,\"USER_PEROFILE_ID\":0}]",
    "USER_PEROFILE_ID": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: For more clearification, I have 2 seperate classes as: 
class jsonArray
{
  constructor(public USER_ID: string, 
    public firstName: string,   
    public lastName: string){}
}

class arrayData {
  constructor(public USER_ID: number, 
              public JsonRawData: jsonArray[],   
              public USER_PEROFILE_ID: number){}
}

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to transform it into a JSON.You'll need to parse it to a JSON.

```
toJson(data) {
  data.JsonRawData = JSON.parse(data.JsonRawData.replace(/\//g, ""));
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object having backslash, So ng-repeate does not get the value as an array. so you should remove the `\` and reassign the object.  like this

in typescript you need replace the backslash by using a loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= this.userData.length; i++) {
            this.userData[i].JsonRawData = this.userData[i].JsonRawData.replace(/\//g, "");

        }
```

Comment: Its a very slow process and it downgrade the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to parse the JsonRawData before looping over it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

```
toObject(items) {
   return JSON.parse(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your Json Data as follow

```
*ngFor="let item of userData;   
  *ngFor="let subitem of toJson(item.JsonRawData)
```

In component.ts file add a method toJson()

```
toJson(data){
JSON.parse(data)
}
```

[Json parsed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwsQk.png)

Comment: It is throwing me the exception as "Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined". Please let me know how to parse it.

Comment: we can go with a method, toJson(item.JsonRawData), do this same in that method JSON.parse(item.JsonRawData)

Comment: After this, I got this error, ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object ' [{"USER_ID":null,"firstName":"sumit","lastName":"joshi","landline":"01127850127","phone":null,"gender":"1","confirmPassword":"","height":"5.7","weight":"84","incomerange":"10000-20000","smokestatus":"Yes","dietstatus":"Veg","workstatus":"job","drinkstatus":"No","religion":"Hindu","mothertounge":"Hindi","rashi":"5","education":"MBA","profession":"Job","address":"Roihini","country":"india","city":"delhi","place":"delhi"}]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.